# sed and special characters

Tags: sed

I'm trying to use sed to replace `</link>` or `</title>` by a space in a file, I'm using.

```
sed -i 's,</link>,,' file.txt
```

if I use the same command but without the / it works, but with it, it doesn't work. Is there a way to do it with sed?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Your command as written here will remove the first occurrence of `</link>` on each line of `file.txt`.

Comment: It looks like your are [trying to parse html with a regexp](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/137158).  Watch out for TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i -e  's/<\/link>/ /g' file.txt
```

the `/` is a command separator for sed, so you need to escape it with `\`

Comment: In his example he uses `,` as separator. This is valid.